# Everybody, go get the Announcer badge!

Tags: discussion

[image]

I finally figured out why it took me so long to get this badge. It's because I was shooting myself in the foot, by always getting the link to share a question from the question title itself so the URL contains a readable URI-cleaned version of the title. Whereas I knew that by using the "share" link, the link becomes *linked* to my account for the purpose of tracking these badges.

### But you can do both!

Snag the "readable" link, like that one I just shared:

```
http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6103/what-factors-affect-a-guitars-ability-to-sustain-a-note
```

And for reference this is what the "share" link below the question gives for me:

```
http://music.stackexchange.com/q/6103/1344
```

And 1344 is my user id number. So you can just add your user id number into the readable URL, sandwiched after the question id number, producing (for me):

```
http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/6103/1344/what-factors-affect-a-guitars-ability-to-sustain-a-note
                              just insert  ^^/1344^^
                         or more generally, "/idno"
                         just after the question number
                         (before the existing slash)
```

So, go on, Announce some stuff! Feel free to just use 1344 if that's easier. :)

Comment: you don't even need anything after your user ID at all - the user readable bit is optional